# File directory path clickable

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview

I want to display a file path text like
"Folder / Subfolder / Subfolder 2 / Final Folder"
and display this on a UILabel/UITextView/anything that works, but allow the user to click on any of the folders like "Folder" or "Subfolder" or "Subfolder2".
I was able to do this with a textview, but if the path is too long I want to make it slideable left and right instead of wrapping, only one liner.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you already have what you want with a textview, why not just make the textview horizontally scrollable only instead of wrapping?

Next, if you really want a different way of doing it, here's one: take each path component, make a custom button for it (or label, or whatever control suits your fancy that you can detect taps on), and as you build up the list, stick them in a horizontally-growing view which is contained in a standard scrollview.

You'll need to update the content size for the scrollview as you add each element (and account for any whitespace between elements you may add as well).